# Join 2 tables results in query timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a few tables created in AWS Athena under "TestDB". These tables are created by running an AWS Glue crawler through the S3 buckets. I am trying to create a new table by joining 2 existing tables under "TestDB". It is a simple left outer join as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTab1
AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    (
      SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
      FROM "TestDB"."tab1" a
      WHERE a.partition_0 = '10-24-2021'
        AND substring(a.datetimestamp, 1, 10) = '2021-10-24'
    )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT  col1, col2, col3,col4
      FROM "TestDB"."tab2" b
      WHERE b.partition_0 = '10-24-2021'
        AND substring(b.datetimestamp,1,10) = '2021-10-24'
    )
    ON (a.col1 = b.col1)
  )
)
```

The query scans around 5GB worth of data but times out after ~30 mins since that is the timeout limit. Other than requesting an increase in timeout limit, is there any other way to create a join of 2 tables on AWS?

Comment: Maybe using AWS Lambda? https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/big-data/automating-bucketing-of-streaming-data-using-amazon-athena-and-aws-lambda/

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to say from the information you provide, but it's probably down to the result becoming very big or an intermediate result becoming big enough for the executors to run out of memory and having to spill to disk.

Does running just the query work? You can also try to run `EXPLAIN SELECT …` to get the query plan and see if that tells you anything.

---

Your query is unnecessarily complex with multiple nested `SELECT` statements. I think Athena's query planner will be smart enough to rewrite it to something like the following, which is easier to read and understand:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TestTab1 AS
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM "TestDB"."tab1" a LEFT JOIN "TestDB"."tab2" b USING (col1)
WHERE a.partition_0 = '10-24-2021'
  AND b.partition_0 = '10-24-2021'
  AND substring(a.datetimestamp, 1, 10) = '2021-10-24' 
  AND substring(b.datetimestamp, 1, 10) = '2021-10-24'
```